# codename one - Initial value to set Picker with Month Or Year

Tags: codenameone

I have Picker (Codename one) to shoe the Only months, the question is how to initial value with current Month.

And I have Picker with Time also I want to show the initila value is the current time.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean a String [Picker](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/spinner/Picker.html) like this:

```
Picker p = new Picker();
p.setStrings("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
p.setSelectedString("Jan");
```

For time just use:

```
// 10:30AM
timePicker.setTime(630);
```

Comment: I think its more likely he wants to transfer the Date to the current selection.